# Python equivalent for MATLAB function frontcon

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, equivalent

Is there a numpy/scipy equivalent to the MATLAB function [frontocon](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/finance/frontcon.html) (mean-variance efficient frontier)?

Answer (score 0):

The only related tools I could find where;

http://www.quantandfinancial.com/

There seems to be some case study code around mean-variance efficient frontier located here;

https://code.google.com/p/quantandfinancial/source/browse/trunk/